# Dirichlet distribution's property

Tags: probability, random-variables

Suppose $(P_1, \cdots, P_K)$ follows a Dirichlet distribution with parameters $(\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_K)$.

Is it true that $(\frac{P_2}{1-P_1}, \ldots, \frac{P_k}{1-P_1})$ follows a Dirichlet distribution with parameters $(\alpha_2, \ldots, \alpha_K)$?

And is independent of $P_1$?

If yes, then how to prove that?

Comment: Look at page 10 in [these notes](https://web.archive.org/web/20150219021331/https://www.ee.washington.edu/techsite/papers/documents/UWEETR-2010-0006.pdf).

Comment: I see :) Thanks!

Comment: I don't get why do we choose $Y_k = Q_k$? Is it just a trick?

Comment: There might be a simpler solution, though.